# Does creating index in Oracle locks the table for reads?

Tags: oracle, indexing, locking

If we specify `ONLINE` in the `CREATE INDEX` statement, the table isn't locked during creation of the index. Without `ONLINE` keyword it isn't possible to perform DML operations on the table. But is the SELECT statement possible on the table meanwhile? After reading the [description of CREATE INDEX statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-INDEX.html) it still isn't clear to me.

I ask about this, because I wonder if it is similar to PostgreSQL or SQL Server:

- In PostgreSQL writes on the table are not possible, but one can still read the table - see [the CREATE INDEX doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createindex.html) > CONCURRENTLY parameter.
- In SQL Server writes on the table are not possible, and additionally if we create a clustered index reads are also not possible - see [the CREATE INDEX doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) > ONLINE parameter.

Comment: yes it is. Practically no ddl  in Oracle blocks reads on underlying tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an index does NOT block other users from reading the table. In general, almost no Oracle DDL commands will prevent users from reading tables.

There are some DDL statements that can cause problems for readers. For example, if you `TRUNCATE` a table, other users who are in the middle of reading that table may get the error `ORA-08103: Object No Longer Exists`. But that's a very destructive change that we would expect to cause problems. I recently found a specific type of foreign key constraint that blocked reading the table, but that was likely a rare bug. I've caused a lot of production problems while adding objects, but so far I've never seen adding an index prevent users from reading the table.